# How to make Nginx find keycloak-tls?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, keycloak

I'm trying to follow up this example https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy/tree/master/contrib/local-environment/kubernetes but with Keycloak.
I want to deploy Keycloak in k8s cluster with kind and helm charts. And having such config in my Values.yaml:

```
keycloak:
  basepath: auth
  username: admin
  password: password
  extraEnv: |
    - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
      value: "true"
  ingress:
    enabled:    true
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    path: /auth/?(.*)
    hosts:
      - keycloak.localtest.me
```

Where keycloak.localtest.me is in my dns hosts. Accessing nginx I see that keycloak configuration is present with *.keycloak.example.com

And in nginx log I see this:

```
Error getting SSL certificate "default/keycloak-tls": local SSL certificate default/keycloak-tls was not found
```

So when I go to `keycloak.localtest.me` nothing happens. How can I access Keycloack? Example http://keycloak.localtest.me/auth/realms/master?

**UPDATE**
@ArghyaSadhu pointed me to this:
`$ kubectl get secret keycloak-tls -n ingress-nginx`
Which gives me: `Error from server (NotFound): secrets "keycloak-tls" not found`

What can I do make this small example work? Do I need to put somewhere keycloak-tls or maybe disable it, but how can I do it?

Comment: For instance here is an example with Dex https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy/tree/master/contrib/local-environment/kubernetes. How can I rewrite it with Keycloak?

Comment: is there a secret `keycloak-tls` in that namespace?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu Not sure, how I can check it?

Comment: `kubectl get secret keycloak-tls -n namespacename`. namespace should be the namespace where ingress controller is deployed

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu `$ kubectl get secret keycloak-tls -n ingress-nginx
Error from server (NotFound): secrets "keycloak-tls" not found`. So that might be the problem as I understand correctly...